# VS 2013 TypeScript Support not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I was using VS 2012 with the Web Essentials plugin. This was working great and I love the preview window.

Just installed VS 2013 Ultimate and upgraded to the latest version where TypeScript. VS 2013 "apparently" has better support \ integration. Nothing seems to work?

Tools > Options > Text Editor > TypeScript .. doesn't seem to have any reference to compile on save or how to enable a preview window.

What am I missing here?

I find posts like this: http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save ... but this would just blow my mind of I went from such a clean and easy solution in VS 2012 to something like this ... really hope I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Essentials no longer includes TypeScript features. You need to install the [TypeScript plugin](http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download) to get TypeScript support in Visual Studio.

You should see the compile-on-save options under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> TypeScript -> Project.

The "preview window" functionality from WE isn't replicated with the TypeScript plugin, but is easily mimicked by having a separate editor window docked side-by-side.

Comment: "but is easily mimicked by having a separate editor window docked side-by-side." wouldn't that keep popping up "file changed on disk. Reload?" Just curious, I don't try to see the js output anymore :)

Comment: That pop-up would only show up once you navigate back to the VS 2013 IDE I believe. Also, you can enable the 'auto-load changes if saved' option in the Tools | Options | Environment menu, which will negate the pop-up every time.

Comment: Yea I forgot about that checkbox (I checked it a long time ago and never looked back) - it's critical

Comment: Under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> TypeScript -> Project (Compile on Save Section) I have the following options:  [] Automatically compile TypeScript files which are NOT part of a project .. then there are two radio buttons under that Use AMD code, Use commonjs code.... the 1st checkbox doesn't seem to make any sense in my context as my files are part of my project?

Comment: Some of the TypeScript settings are now available in project properties (right-click on the project in solution explorer, select `properties` and then pick the TypeScript tab on the properties window).

Comment: Thanks, all these comments combined helped me get back to where I needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

we can do it by choosing **CommonJS** option under **Module system** in Project Properties. Hope it will help .